# Why is floating point value saved incorrectly in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, floating-point

We saved a value of 2.01 in a `float` column in MySQL.

Then, after we applied the `avg` function, it returned 2.009999990463257

Why is this happening?

Here is the query we are using:

```
SELECT avg(height)  FROM `students` where class='b1'
```

Comment: floats do not store precise values....short explanation: basically, for the same reason you cannot write 1/3 in decimal; floats can only "write" precise halves, quarters, eights, sixteenths, etc.... _it's a bit more complicated than that, involving exponents etc... but that is the gist of it_

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)